# Shell hangs when doing command from ssh

Tags: shell, ssh

I'm trying to automate a server update process.
What this should do is check for `git diff` files and list them, to later be copied from one place to the other.

Here's my script on my local machine:

## update_frontend.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh [login details] -t -t 'bash -s' < ~/Scripts/update_frontend_cmd.sh
```

## update_frontend_cmd.sh

```
SOURCE=/var/www/git_front/mydir_front
TARGET=/var/www/front
dothis=

cd "$SOURCE"
for i in $(git diff --name-only origin/master master)
    do
    x=`echo $i | sed 's/mydir\///'`
        dothis=`echo "
$dothis
cp './mydir/$x' '$TARGET/$x'"`
    done

git pull
eval $dothis
```

Problem is, after any first input from me (be it login for git pull, or if I remove it, any other command I try to execute) causes the shell to hang.
I just get a blank line an infinite waiting. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: For starters, add `set -x` to the top of your script to trace its execution and to see where it stops.You shouldn't use single quotes around variables like `$x` because then they will be literally expanded to `$x` not the value of `x`.

Comment: The script runs entirely - when it's done I'm thrown to the shell, and then any input causes a hang. Entering the shell manually with ssh doesn't cause the hang. As for the single quotes, notice it's part of a multiline string that starts a bit higher, which is in double quotes. The string output is fine when I test it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "any first input from me"?

Comment: I mean as a shell would expect keyboard input, I input any command and as soon as I hit enter that's it. But it doesn't execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your `update_frontend_cmd.sh` has been processed, you are at the end of the input. ssh does not simple switch back to keyboard input from that.

What you could consider is running a screen session on the remote machine and execute commands in there. Then reconnect once you are done.

A more simple possibility is pushing the script to the server (`scp`, or better pushing via `git`) and executing it locally.

Comment: Ended up copying the script to the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the `-t` options from `ssh` invocation, and the session will terminate once `EOF` is reached on `stdin`.

Comment: But then I couldn't pass the script properly, I've tried before.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
( echo 'echo yes'; echo 'exit') | ssh me@localhost -t -t 'bash -s'
```

Try replacing the `echo 'echo yes'` with your `cat`.

Meow.